# Adding TLS certificate to the API request with exception: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: .net, api, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

To be able to use some API, I have to use the TLS certificate (in 1.1 version).

My code looks like:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://someapi/request/");

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(postData);
request.KeepAlive = false;

request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"d:\TLScertificate.p12", "password");  

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

try
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

    if (!store.Certificates.Contains(certificate))
    {
        store.Add(certificate);
    }

    int indexOfCertificate = store.Certificates.IndexOf(certificate);
    certificate = store.Certificates[indexOfCertificate];
}
finally
{
    store.Close();
}

request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
request.PreAuthenticate = true;

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())) // Exception
{
}
```

During `request.GetResponse()` I always get exception: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

The provider answered me that:

> There need be,
>
> Root Ca v1 test.pem in your Truststore and
>   TLSCertificate in your Keystore

Please, advise me what should I do with the file .pem ? It should be added to the request, the same as the TLScertificate.p12 file? When I add second X509Certificate2 (without any password) to the request, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use the loaded cert right away to the request

```
   X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"d:\TLScertificate.p12", "password");
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
```

The pem file has to be imported into your computers KeyStore
mmc -> File -> Add/Remove Snap-in -> Certificates

This can help converting pem to crt
[Convert .pem to .crt and .key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732826/convert-pem-to-crt-and-key)

Comment: But when I install TLScertificate.p12, the ROOT CA.pem is also installed automatically and I can see it in Trusted Root Certification Authorities in mmc. Still, I get the same exception...

Comment: Try this to ensure that your machine accepts the remote cert `request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback  = certcallback; 

private static bool certcallback(
         object sender,
         System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
         System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
         System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
      
        return true;
      }`

If after that you still have problems it possible that you were given a bad cert... I had the same problem. Debugged for one day...

Comment: I have added this callback, unfortunately exception is the same.

Comment: Sorry... no clue, but you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112515/httpwebrequest-results-in-the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-sec